# How to run Client-Server on different computers using Sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, unix-socket

I am able to run a client and server on the same computer on two different terminals in Linux. Now I want to run the same model on two different computers. I am guessing there is more to this than just changing the IP address and the port number to that of the Server.

Any guidance on the matter is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the port is forwarded in your router and exceptions for the port is added to the firewall. Then you should be ready to go!

If you have the computers in the same network you can do it without forwarding your port.

Comment: Currently, I am running the client and server on a Debian VM. How do I go about configuring the router and the firewall on the VM?

Comment: @user2058668 Check this link for more information on forwarding ports: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm